# Error safeguarding the input and output file descriptors

Tags: c++, unix, pipe, file-descriptor

Alright, I'm doing a pipe to connect with the children of my process.
First of nothing I tried to do a safeguard of my fds so I can access them later for some stuff, but somehow it just gets stuck when duplicating the fds.

```
int pipeFd [2];
int pid;
pipe (pipeFd);

//Safeguard of the Original FDs
int fdSG [2];
perror ("fdsg create");
dup2 (1, fdSG [1]);
perror ("dup2 sfg1");
dup2 (0, fdSG [0]);
perror ("dup2 sfg2");
dup2 (pipeFd [1], 1);
```

The program gets stuck in the last instruction showed here.

The terminal output is the following:

```
fdsg create: Success
dup2 sfg1: Bad file descriptor
dup2 sfg2: Bad file descriptor
dup2: Bad file descriptor
```

Does any of you have any clue why this is happening?

Comment: Your code seems ok. I  suggest to do a  strace.

Comment: It's not correct to call `perror` if there wasn't actually an error. (You should check return values)

Comment: I called `perror` to check in every line if there was an error, in sort of a debug attempt to understand what was happening. I was not gonna let it like this. Thanks anyway for the advice.

Comment: `perror` doesn't check if there was an error, it tells you what `errno` is. If you want to check for an error you need to look at what `dup2` and `pipe` actually return.

Comment: Well, it doesn't check for it, but if there was an error it tells you which one it was and if it wasn't any it returns success..

Comment: `perror` can and will print an error that has nothing to do with your problem if you don't check return values. You need to check return values.

Comment: Oh, true, you are right, sorry for my stubbornness. I'll check them now.

Comment: Well, `errno` seems to return the same error as `perror` does.. on both first `dup2` it returns `Bad File Descriptor`, and it gets stuck in the third..

Comment: `errno` is what `perror` uses. The functions themselves return an `int` that indicates if you need to look at `errno`/`perror`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code you've shown you haven't initalised `fdSG`. That's not correct, the arguments of `dup2` both need to be valid file descriptors.

Since you seem to want to copy a fd rather than replace an existing one you should use `dup` for those backup copies instead, it picks a free `fd` and uses that. (Alternatively you could initalise `fdSG` to be valid fds too).

From the manpage:

> `dup()` uses the lowest-numbered unused descriptor for the new descriptor.

Comment: Thx, seems that it worked, dumb of me for not paying attention on that detail.